# Mutate column conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm an R programmer trying to get into Python. In R, when I want to mutate a column conditionally, I use:

```
col = dplyr::mutate(col, ifelse(condition, if_true(x), if_false(x))
```

In Python, how does one mutate a column value conditionally? Here's my minimally reproducible example:

```
def act(cntnt):
    def do_thing(cntnt):
        return(cntnt + "has it")
    def do_other_thing(cntnt):
        return(cntnt + "nope")
    has_abc = cntnt.str.contains.contains("abc")
    if has_abc == T:
        cntnt[has_abc].apply(do_thing)
    else:
        cntnt[has_abc].apply(do_other_thing)
```

Comment: Please can you add a small example of your problem and the expected outcome? Also, I assume that `if has_abc == T:` is actually `if has_abc == True:`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), which is essentially the pandas equivalent to `mutate` in `dplyr`. Your conditional statement can be written with a list comprehension, or using vectorized methods (see below).

Take an example dataframe, lets call it `df`:

```
> df
             a
1   0.50212013
2   1.01959213
3  -1.32490344
4  -0.82133375
5   0.23010548
6  -0.64410737
7  -0.46565442
8  -0.08943858
9   0.11489957
10 -0.21628132
```

## `R` / `dplyr`:

In `R`, you can use `mutate` with `ifelse` to make a column based on a condition (in this example, it will be `'pos'` when column a is greater than `0`):

```
df = dplyr::mutate(df, col = ifelse(df$a > 0, 'pos', 'neg'))
```

And the resulting `df`:

```
> df
             a col
1   0.50212013 pos
2   1.01959213 pos
3  -1.32490344 neg
4  -0.82133375 neg
5   0.23010548 pos
6  -0.64410737 neg
7  -0.46565442 neg
8  -0.08943858 neg
9   0.11489957 pos
10 -0.21628132 neg
```

## `Python` / `Pandas`

In `pandas`, use `assign` with a list comprehension:

```
df = df.assign(col = ['pos' if a > 0 else 'neg' for a in df['a']])
```

The resulting `df`:

```
>>> df
          a  col
0  0.502120  pos
1  1.019592  pos
2 -1.324903  neg
3 -0.821334  neg
4  0.230105  pos
5 -0.644107  neg
6 -0.465654  neg
7 -0.089439  neg
8  0.114900  pos
9 -0.216281  neg
```

The `ifelse` you were using in `R` is replaced by a [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835952/6671176).

## Variations on this:

You don't *have* to use `assign`: you can create a new column directly on the `df` without creating a copy if you want:

```
df['col'] = ['pos' if a > 0 else 'neg' for a in df['a']]
```

Also, instead of a list comprehension, you could use one of `numpy`'s vectorized methods for conditional statements, for example, `np.select`:

```
import numpy as np
df['col'] = np.select([df['a'] > 0], ['pos'], 'neg')
# or
df = df.assign(col = np.select([df['a'] > 0], ['pos'], 'neg'))
```

Comment: Thank you! Great thorough answer.

Comment: Top notch answer my dude!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the condition (and its negation) for logical indexing:

```
has_abc = cntnt.str.contains("abc")
cntnt[ has_abc].apply(do_thing)
cntnt[~has_abc].apply(do_other_thing)
```

Comment: I can't help but think this has jumped the gun, there's no data at all given

Comment: @roganjosh Eh? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Your answer changed quite substantially from the very first one you posted, now it's more likely to be correct. But there's still `if has_abc == T:` in the question so it seems the question isn't complete, and you could potentially address the problem with `np.where` if example data was given, rather than a non-vectorised approach in two stages

Comment: @roganjosh I see your point. If the OP rephrases their question, then the answer may be optimized. But _first make it right, then make it fast_.

Comment: Thank you! Seeing how to do the inverse of the series of booleans helps me a lot.

Comment: @DyZ why is there a two contains in first line. Is it a typo?

Comment: @Dark I blindly copied it from the OP. A typo.