# Replace specific values in a panda column with a value determined by a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import country_converter as coco
cc = coco.CountryConverter()

example = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Country': {0: 'Fiji', 1: 'Tanzania', 2: 'W. Sahara', 3: 'Canada', 4: 'United States of America', 5: 'Kazakhstan', 6: 'Uzbekistan', 7: 'Papua New Guinea', 8: 'Indonesia', 9: 'Argentina', 10: 'Chile', 11: 'Dem. Rep. Congo', 12: 'Somalia', 13: 'Kenya', 14: 'Sudan', 15: 'Chad', 16: 'Haiti', 17: 'Dominican Rep.', 18: 'Russia', 19: 'Bahamas', 20: 'Falkland Is.', 21: 'Norway'}, 'iso': {0: 'FJI', 1: 'TZA', 2: 'ESH', 3: 'CAN', 4: 'USA', 5: 'KAZ', 6: 'UZB', 7: 'PNG', 8: 'IDN', 9: 'ARG', 10: 'CHL', 11: 'COD', 12: 'SOM', 13: 'KEN', 14: 'SDN', 15: 'TCD', 16: 'HTI', 17: 'DOM', 18: 'RUS', 19: 'BHS', 20: 'FLK', 21: '-99'}}
)

                     Country  iso
0                       Fiji  FJI
1                   Tanzania  TZA
2                  W. Sahara  ESH
3                     Canada  CAN
4   United States of America  USA
5                 Kazakhstan  KAZ
6                 Uzbekistan  UZB
7           Papua New Guinea  PNG
8                  Indonesia  IDN
9                  Argentina  ARG
10                     Chile  CHL
11           Dem. Rep. Congo  COD
12                   Somalia  SOM
13                     Kenya  KEN
14                     Sudan  SDN
15                      Chad  TCD
16                     Haiti  HTI
17            Dominican Rep.  DOM
18                    Russia  RUS
19                   Bahamas  BHS
20              Falkland Is.  FLK
21                    Norway  -99
```

I would like python to attempt:

```
example['iso'] = cc.convert(names = example['Country'], to = 'ISO3')
```

but **ONLY** if the value of `iso=-99`

I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518607/mutate-column-conditionally), so I attempted:

```
example = example.assign(col = [(cc.convert(names = example['Country'], to = 'ISO3')) if iso = '-99' else (example['iso']) for iso in example['iso']])
```

But that is not the right syntax.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: `example.loc[example['iso'] == '-99', 'iso'] = 'ISO3'`?

Comment: Define a small function and try the `apply` method

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But the result should be the evaluation of the function, not a specific string. Can I replace the string with the function?

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(row):
    try:
        if int(row['iso']) == -99:
            return cc.convert(names=example[row['country']].strip(), to='ISO3')
    except:
        pass
    return row['iso']

example['iso'] = example.apply(f, axis=1)
```

If you want to be more computationally efficient, you could run

```
idx = example['iso'].apply(int) == -99
example['iso'][idx] = example[idx].apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have you tested this? For me nothing changes if I apply this solution.

Comment: Is the -99 possibly a string or float value?

Comment: I tried both, because I assumed it would be a string.

Comment: I edited my solu tion to converti it to an integer

Comment: wait this won't work, let me edit some more: DONE

Comment: I think the problem now is that the `if int(row['iso']) == -99:`  fails when it finds an actual string value : `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FJI'`

Comment: Oh, right, you'd need a try/except

Comment: Norway needs to be stripped, is the problem. It now works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
condition = df.iso.eq('-99')
df.iso.loc[condition] = df.Country[condition].apply(lambda x: cc.convert(x, to='ISO3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use np.select for this particular problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

example = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Country': {0: 'Fiji', 1: 'Tanzania', 2: 'W. Sahara', 3: 'Canada', 4: 'United States of America', 5: 'Kazakhstan', 6: 'Uzbekistan', 7: 'Papua New Guinea', 8: 'Indonesia', 9: 'Argentina', 10: 'Chile', 11: 'Dem. Rep. Congo', 12: 'Somalia', 13: 'Kenya', 14: 'Sudan', 15: 'Chad', 16: 'Haiti', 17: 'Dominican Rep.', 18: 'Russia', 19: 'Bahamas', 20: 'Falkland Is.', 21: 'Norway'}, 'iso': {0: 'FJI', 1: 'TZA', 2: 'ESH', 3: 'CAN', 4: 'USA', 5: 'KAZ', 6: 'UZB', 7: 'PNG', 8: 'IDN', 9: 'ARG', 10: 'CHL', 11: 'COD', 12: 'SOM', 13: 'KEN', 14: 'SDN', 15: 'TCD', 16: 'HTI', 17: 'DOM', 18: 'RUS', 19: 'BHS', 20: 'FLK', 21: '-99'}}
)
df = pd.DataFrame(example)
condition_list = [df['iso'] == '-99']
choice_list = ['ISO3']
#If the condition is met use the choice else keep the data as it is
df['iso'] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, df['iso'])
df
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think this actually answers my question.

Comment: Oh sorry I must have misunderstood the question, are you trying to change the 'Country' column to ISO3 if the 'iso' column is '-99'?